# Single Click Application .on attaches too many events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have single click application that consist of three parts; a header, some content and a footer.

I keep my menu inside of the header file. Depending on a user choice, when clicked on one of the elements of the menu which look like this:

```
<li class="submenu">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="icon-tasks"></i> 
        <span>Timesheet</span> 
        <i class="arrow icon-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" id="display_timesheet">Unpaid Hours</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" id="display_paid_timesheet">Paid Hours</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

the content part of the page will change. One of the pages that I load inside of the content part of the page has the following code:

```
$('#confirm_modal').on('click', '#confirm', function(e) {
    console.log('TEST1');
});
```

The #confirm modal is located in the footer part of the page which doesn't get reloaded when clicked on the element of the menu.

Here is the problem. When I click on the element of the menu that loads "Paid Hours" 5 times in a row and then I click on the #confirm button. It will display TEST1 five times. I don't want that. It looks like every time I click on that element of the menu, it reattaches another handler. I think that I should use .off but I'm not sure where or on what action.

Thanks

Comment: Try `.one()` instead of `.on()`

Comment: Please show the code where you attach your handler. Your guess about attaching the handler multiple times sounds like the issue. You could attach some code to the `hide` event of the dialog (assuming it has one) to call `off()` on the required elements.

Comment: @DevlshOne what if the button within the modal should be able to be clicked multiple times?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's a good what if, but since the OP is pretty vague about that, I suggested the `.one()`. It could be that he's bubbling through the DOM and just needs to `e.stopPropagation()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

that's because the `div` or any other HTML that you use with the id `confirm_modal` is placed in your footer and never reloaded as you say, and you add the `on click handler` like this

```
$('#confirm_modal').on('click', '#confirm', function(e) {
    console.log('TEST1');
});
```

every time the content part of the page is changed. This will add an `on click handler` for `#confirm_modal` which triggered if you click on `#confirm` inside it. Since you load the content page for 5 times, the handler will be attached to `#confirm_modal` for 5 times and causing the console to log `TEST1` for 5 times too. So what you need is to add the `on click handler` once on `document ready` or `page load`, and not every time your new content page is loaded

### Edit:

Yes you can unattach it using `.off` like in [Kenny answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802213/single-click-application-on-attaches-too-many-events/25802715#25802715), but if you have the authority to modify the script, it's better to `attach` it only one time on `page load` rather than `removing` and `adding` the `handler` everytime new content is loaded, since your `handler` is still the same for every content that's loaded.

It will be an exception though if your `on click handler` is different for each content that's loaded but using the same button

Comment: Is there anyway to unattach it using .off?

Comment: @user1029829 if you attach it *only* on DOMReady, you won't need to use `off()` - as it will only be attached once.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you just add a line

```
     $('#confirm_modal').off('click', '#confirm')
```

before

```
$('#confirm_modal').on('click', '#confirm', function(e) {
    console.log('TEST1');
});
```

Like this

```
$('#confirm_modal').off('click', '#confirm')
$('#confirm_modal').on('click', '#confirm', function(e) {
    console.log('TEST1');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are registering a new click handler on every time your content changes.

Use [**`jQuery.One()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of [**`jQuery.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
[**`jQuery.One()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) bind handler only once.

Try this-

```
$('#confirm_modal').one('click', function(e) {
    console.log('TEST1');
});
```

**Update:-**

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/xk5qe4vy/)